# looking for help with the Latin word for "open"

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, translation-check, conjugation

I am making a shirt for our locksport group and was thinking about incorporating a take on the "Veni,Vidi,Vici" phrase. At locksport competitions it is customary to call out "OPEN" when we get a lock open so our time can be recorded. The phrase I want to use Veni,Vidi, and then the Latin word for "open".

In my research I came up with 2 options aperui and reseravi. Is there another option? If not what one would be the most "correct".

I am also thinking about doing the phrase as a  plural "we came, we saw, we opened" statement, from what I understand you can add the -mus suffix to make the Latin plural form of a word.

Any help or suggestions are appreciated, Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think in this case, *resero* wins, because its primary meaning means "unlock."

For *aperio*, the meanings derive from the action of opening a door or even uncovering an object. The verb *recludo* (*reclusi* = "I have opened") is similar in this regard.

This might work if the convention were about door locks, but for "I opened = I unlocked", I think *resero* is your best bet, since it not only means "unlock" etymologically (*re*- = "back", *sero* = "I fastened," from [*sera*](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dsera) = "bolt"), but it's [frequently used](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aalphabetic+letter%3DR%3Aentry+group%3D21%3Aentry%3Dresero2) with doors and gates and the action of unbarring them for entry or exit.

To make it plural, you are correct that you merely change the -i ending to -imus:

> **Venimus, vidimus, reseravimus**.
>
> We came, we saw, we unlocked.

Comment: Edit: Wrong link! I originally linked to [this resero](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dresero1), but that's a 3rd conjugation verb. The right one is [this resero (reserare)](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aalphabetic+letter%3DR%3Aentry+group%3D21%3Aentry%3Dresero2).

Comment: Great thanks for your help